# Using matching entries only, print file A line if column values is between two other columns values in file B

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file1

```
A 1
A 20
B 17
B 33
C 10
C 20
E 7
```

and another tab delim file2

```
A 1  5
A 6  20
B 1  10
B 30 60
C 10 20
E 1  6
```

I need to print the lines in file1 for which col1 file1 = col1 file2 and value in col2 file1 falls within the ranges in cols 2 and 3 of file2.

The output would look like

```
A 1
A 20
B 33
C 10
C 20
```

I'm trying

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}; ($1) in a{if($2=(a[$1] >= $2 && a[$1] <=$3) {print}}1'  file1  file2
```

But it's not working.

Comment: file2 has multiple min/max for each col1. For example, is 1<=A<=5 with 3<=A<=20 supposed to be interpreted as 1<=A<=20 ?

Comment: You can think of it as starts and ends mapping to a same object. A has two intervals 1 to 5 and 3 to 20. So A 1 falls into the range A 1 to 5 and A 20 falls into the range A 3 to 20. They are then printed in the output. Basically mapping single points from file1 in intervals decribed in file2.

Comment: Yes. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store multiple ranges, you really want to use arrays of arrays or lists. awk doesn't support them directly but they can be emulated. In this case arrays of arrays seem likely to be more efficient.

```
awk '
    # store each range from file2
    FNR==NR {
        n = ++q[$1]
        min[$1 FS n] = $2
        max[$1 FS n] = $3
        next
    }

    # process file1
    n = q[$1] { # if no q entry, line cannot be in range
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            if ( min[$1 FS i]<=$2 && $2<=max[$1 FS i]) {
                print
                next
            }
    }
' file2 file1
```

Each min/max range needs to be stored separately. By maintaining a counter (`q[$1]`) of occurrences of each different value of col1 (`$1`), we ensure creation of a distinct new array element `[$1 FS n]`.

Subsequently, when checking the ranges, we know that any particular value of col1 occurs precisely `q[$1]` times.

Comment: It runs just fine but unfortunately no output.

Comment: I mistyped `max[$2 ...` instead of `max[$1...`

Comment: Hummm. Still not working. Sorry, I think I'm not explaining very well. I just posted my dumb solution to this. Hopefully that can help me explain better. Thxs!

Comment: Odd, it works here with the data you posted in your question. You did notice the swapped arguments? file2 is listed before file1

Comment: Finally figured there was some prob with my input files. This super works. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @jhnc sorry for coming back to this question after so long, but do you mean I should have max[$2.... in the two instances in this script? thxs

Comment: No, I meant that my original answer had a typo. The edited version has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My desperate solution to this was to manipulate my file2 into this using some basic awk operations

```
A 1 gene_starts
A 5 gene_ends
A 6 gene_starts
A 20 gene_ends
B 1 gene_starts
B 10 gene_ends
B 30 gene_starts
B 60 gene_ends
C 10 gene_starts
C 20 gene_ends
E 1 gene_starts
E 6 gene_ends
```

So, that I could sort the two files 1 and 2, and grab lines between gene_starts and genes_ends

```
sort -V -k1,2 file1 file2 | awk '/gene_starts/,/gene_ends/' | awk '!length($3)'
```

But this allowed me to get only

```
A 20
B 33
C 20
```

because sorting puts lines from file1 matching gene_starts before them. 
So, to get A 1 and C 10, I had to do filter gene_ends out of my file2 and use

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in c)' file2 file1
```

to get the gene_starts lines that were also in file1 and add then to my output

Comment: Also notice that this doesn't work if there are overlapping intervals in file2.