# Merge files where value of a column lies between values of two columns in the other file

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file1

```
A 1 0.1 0.2
A 20 0.3 0.3
B 17 0.1 0.7
B 33 0.33 0.55
C 10 0.2 0.3
C 20 0.0 0.55
E 7 0.44 0.3
```

and another tab delim file2

```
A 1  5 aie
A 6  20 cal
B 1  10 nan
B 30 60 ota
C 10 20 car
E 1  6 err
```

I want to merge the two files where col1 file1 = col1 file2 and value in col2 file1 falls within the ranges in cols 2 and 3 of file2.

The output would look like:

```
A 1 0.1 0.2 A 1  5 aie
A 20 0.3 0.3 A 6  20 cal
B 33 0.33 0.55 B 30 60 ota
C 10 0.2 0.3 C 10 20 car
C 20 0.0 0.55 C 10 20 car
```

Notice that some lines in file 1 will match to the same line in file 2.

I've tried couple approaches:

1)

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } FNR == NR { val[$1] = $2; d[$1] = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4; next }
     FNR != NR { if ($1 in val && val[$1] >= $2 && val[$1] <= $3)
print d[$1], $1, $2, $3, $4 
}' file1 file2
```

2)

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; c[$1]= $4; next} 
                 {for(k in a) 
                      if(k+0<=$1 && $1+0<=a[k]) 
print a[k] , b[k] , c[k], $1, $2, $3, $4
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Last time you asked this question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/56709884/1745001) you accepted the first answer you got which effectively discouraged anyone else from answering and then you decided it didn't work for you and posted your own workaround which you said also didn't work for you. So - don't do that this time around. Wait a few hours, test the answers you get, and then accept the one that works "best" for you.

Comment: K, will do! This one is a little different from that other one. I need to whole lines from both files. I never know what's best... to comment on an older question or post a new one. Thanks

Comment: Comment on answers to a question til you get a working answer, then accept an answer. After that if/when your requirements change and you can't figure out how to solve the latest problem ask a new question about that problem and include a reference to that previous question if it'd be useful.

Comment: You just accepted the first answer you got again ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209968/1745001)). See [my first comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209168/merge-files-where-value-of-a-column-lies-between-values-of-two-columns-in-the-ot/57209968#comment100926046_57209168).

Comment: oh duh. I now understand what you mean. K will do that next. For some reason I thought the code was to accept answers as fast as they come. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    c = ++cnt[$1]
    beg[$1,c] = $2
    end[$1,c] = $3
    map[$1,c] = $0
    next
}
{
    for (c=1; c<=cnt[$1]; c++) {
        if ( (beg[$1,c] <= $2) && ($2 <= end[$1,c]) ) {
            print $0, map[$1,c]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
A       1       0.1     0.2     A       1       5       aie
A       20      0.3     0.3     A       6       20      cal
B       33      0.33    0.55    B       30      60      ota
C       10      0.2     0.3     C       10      20      car
C       20      0.0     0.55    C       10      20      car
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works for you but you really should consider the advice I gave you in comments under your question.